# Mysql Query Enhancement

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have this 2 two views. I made a view out of them because they have dependencies on other tables. I then created a query joining them together. Two queries separately has over 30k plus data.

Sample Query would be like:

```
 Select main.*, detail.* 
 FROM main_data as main 
 INNER JOIN detail_data AS details ON (main.id = detail.main_id)
 WHERE main.column_data LIKE '%something%'
```

This is slow but if I comment out the "detail.*" on the column section with the join being there is returns the data very fast. What is wrong here?
The expected amount of data is only 20 rows. Still takes very long to perform the select. What makes it slow?

I'd like to add that the joined tables on the view are correct. It is joined accordingly. Like I said If queried separately it returns a lot of data in a very short time.

For more details, actually there is a third table here where both table are a child to. I changed it up to something like this. It improves the performance a bit.

```
 Select main.*, detail.* 
 FROM parent_data AS par
 INNER JOIN main_data as main ON (par.id = detail.par_id)
 INNER JOIN detail_data AS details ON (par.id = detail.par_id)
 WHERE main.column_data LIKE '%something%'
```

I made a EXPLAIN SELECT on the exact tables and this is there result:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just `SELECT *` ?

Comment: Still the same as "main.*, detail.* "...  very slow.

Comment: Are those columns indexed?

Comment: show details_data sechema..you can share "show create table details_data" output...

Comment: Yes, they are indexed.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  If it does not start with `main`, then I _will_ have some advice.  (Otherwise, I _might_ have some advice.)

Comment: @RickJames I executed the EXPLAIN SELECT on my view and it shows why. One reference in my 'detail' table to another table shows 13k+ value. The problem is that I used inner join and have setup a primary key and foreign key in the table. So what am I lacking?

Comment: `asset` is `parent_data`??  Or what?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason the query slows down if you include fields in the resultset from `detail` table is that `detail.main_id` is indexed, therefore if no fields are selected from `detail`, then mysql does not have to touch `detail` table, it is enough to use the index only. If you do include some fields from that table, then simple index lookup will not be enough, mysql will have to open `detail` table and get the corresponding records from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `left join` cause you need only connected records from right table:

```
Select main.*, detail.*
FROM main_data as main
LEFT JOIN detail_data AS details
 ON (main.id = detail.main_id AND main.column_data LIKE '%something%')
```

Comment: cannot use left join.. must use inner join for this